# How to define a class to make a function work using progress_apply()?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with where each column contains text. I want to create a new column which tells me whether at least one of the text columns is not in English. I would also like to make use of progess_apply() to see the work in progress.

From what I read, batch_detection from deep_translator makes the most sense, as I can detect the language of many strings and receive a list of detected languages. batch_detection is a function that needs an input and specified parameters, so I thought of creating a class with a custom function to make use of progress_apply:

```
class detector:
    def __init__(self):
        self=self
    def detect(self, input):
        if any (batch_detection(input, api_key = my_key) != 'en'):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

df['non_en'] = df.progress_apply(detector.detect, axis=0)
```

But then I receive the roor:

> TypeError: detect() missing 1 required positional argument: 'input'

What am I doing wrong? Is there maybe a simpler way to solve this?

Comment: What do you think would be the benefit _of creating a class_? Of course an ordinary function is _a simpler way to solve this_.